# HABTM delete/push without Object, only id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a series of check boxes with category values, a classical Items >< Categories scenario, associated with `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

The thing is I DON'T want to find the object to append or delete an association, I want to use only the ID, the integer.

I really take care of my database and I don't want to do unnecessary queries. I know that ID exists, and the Item exists, and if doesn't exist, I don't care. I just want to execute the delete in a clean way.

NO!

```
@item.categories << @category
@item.categories.delete @category
```

YES!

```
@item.categories << id
@item.categories.delete id
```

or, but so dirty

```
@category = Category.new
@category.id = id
@item.categories << @category
@item.categories.delete @category
```

Any thoughts guys?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
@item.category_ids << id
@item.category_ids.delete id
```

This way you get an array of integers (the ids), and not an array with the objects.

Comment: That doesn't work. Here is some doc:
collection_singular_ids => Returns an array of the associated objects’ ids.
collection_singular_ids=ids => Replace the collection by the objects identified by the primary keys in ids.
There is no collection_singular_ids << or delete methods.

Comment: The << and delete are Array methods. The array which they are applied to is the one being returned by the first method in the doc you quoted. The id is an integer, btw.